# Increase animation speed according to the swipe speed in unity for Android

Tags: unity, unityscript

I have the animation done through Maya and brought the FBX file to unity. Here is my code to calculate the speed of the swipe:

```
Vector2 speedMeasuredInScreenWidthsPerSecond =(Input.touches[0].deltaPosition / Screen.width) *     Input.touches[0].deltaTime;
```

Now I wanted to take `speedMeasuredInScreenWidthsPerSecond` and use it to increase the animation speed accordingly like this:

```
animation["gmeChaAnimMiddle"].speed=Mathf.Round(speedMeasuredInScreenWidthsPerSecond);
```

However, this results in an error that I need to convert Vector2 to float.

So how do I overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use length of your vector ([Vector2.magnitude](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector2-magnitude.html)).

In your case it can be:

```
animation["gmeChaAnimMiddle"].speed=Mathf.Round(speedMeasuredInScreenWidthsPerSecond.magnitude);
```

Comment: thank u for the answer...but now after i have written animation.play("gmeChaAnimMiddle"), the problem seems that only last few frames of the animation is being played not the whole animation.....So can u tell me wat the problem is??? thank u

Comment: @rohit, that sounds like a different problem.  You should ask that as a new Question.